# How to force Chrome to open as new application from .desktop file

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, launcher, icons, .desktop

Google Chrome has an option to launch a web page as a windowed 'Chrome app', which, when used with Gnome Desktop, will create a special .desktop file which can be used to run Chrome in a stand-alone mode with its own icon displayed in the dash/dock and window switcher.

The problem with this mode is that Chrome tries to impersonate the GTK theme resulting in a pretty ugly window title. It also takes up unnecessary space displaying the address bar and other controls at the top of the window. This is especially true when using an insecure connection, which is typical for accessing locally-hosted applications.

An alternative is to launch Chrome with a `--app=http://example.com` option, which results in a much nicer experience. A comparison of the appearance of the two modes is at the end of this question.

I can create a .desktop file to launch Chrome with the `--app` option and an icon I specify, but this results in the new window being grouped with other Chrome instances, which all share the same generic Chrome icon entry in the dash/dock and window switcher.

Is there an option, either in Chrome or Gnome, to force the window that results from the .desktop file to behave as a completely separate application?

Google Chrome app:
[image: Chrome app]

Google Chrome with `--app` option:
[image: Chrome with --app option]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [applicationize](https://github.com/eladnava/applicationize) to create chrome apps.
[image: Create extension]

Drop your extension in chrome://extensions
[image: Chrome extensions]

An example of a .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Version=1.0  
Type=Application  
Name=Netflix Chrome (Application).  
GenericName=Netflix Browser  
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;  
Exec=/opt/google/chrome-unstable/chrome --user-data-dir=/home/USER/.config/google-chrome-netflix --profile-directory=Netflix --class=google-chrome-netflix --app-id=mhmidglabaofnaganlmeicdfedljohpf --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end %U  
Icon=chrome-mhmidglabaofnaganlmeicdfedljohpf-Netflix  
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;image/webp;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;  
StartupNotify=true  
Terminal=false  
StartupWMClass=crx_mhmidglabaofnaganlmeicdfedljohpf
```

<sup>Don't forget to adjust `--user-data-dir=` and extension id.</sup>

Comment: Nice clean solution.

Comment: yepp, start using it myself.

Comment: Unfortunately the Chrome extensions that this produces no longer work. When trying to open one, Chrome shows the message "Old versions of Chrome apps won't work on Linux devices after December 2022."

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here:

https://blog.aldomann.com/jupyterlab-desktop-on-linux/

Create the jupyter-lab.desktop:

```
touch ~/.local/share/applications/jupyter-lab.desktop
```

Then write the code below (Replace `<user>` by your username) and save it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=JupyterLab
GenericName=JupyterLab
Comment=JupyterLab is the next-generation web-based user interface for Project Jupyter
Keywords=python;tensorflow;keras
Exec= bash -c "/usr/bin/env PATH=/home/<user>/.anaconda3/bin/:$PATH /home/<user>/.anaconda3/bin/jupyter lab"
StartupWMClass=Google-chrome
Categories=Development;Science;IDE;Qt;
Icon=jupyter-lab
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/x-python3;text/x-python;application/x-ipynb+json;e
```

Restart Gnome section (Press Alt+F2 and inside of the dialog write 'r')

Create a new .desktop file to Google Chrome:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

Then if not exist a line with `StartupWMClass=google-chrome` add this line otherwise replace it by the code below:

```
StartupWMClass=google-chrome
```

Get an icon to Jupyter. For example:

https://blog.aldomann.com/assets/img/jupyter-lab.svg

and save it at `~/.local/share/icons`.